# What terms describe who pays for a meal?

Tags: geography

I have heard the terms *go dutch* and *AA* used to mean that, when two or more people eat at a restaurant, each will pay only the price of their own dish. Also *treat* is used to describe the act of one person paying for the meal of themselves and another.

- Has anyone conducted a study on the terms used and their geographic distribution?
- In which regions of the world are these terms used?
- Are there other terms which might be more popular in North America, the UK, Australia, and New Zealand?

Comment: I don't think this question has any one answer, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: I need to obtain a general idea of which terms are used and where. A good answer would list at least a few of the most common terms and in which countries they are typically used or provide a link to a study or map.

Comment: That isn't what StackExchange or ELU is for, though.

Comment: I thought this was English Language and "Usage". Typically, an examination of usage requires one to consider geography. I need to explain how to use these words. If people do not know where it is used, my explanation will be incomplete.

Comment: ELU is designed for every question to have one answer--one *right* answer. While lists are helpful, they are not in line with the purposes of this site.

Comment: The TeX exchange site has handled questions which ask for list questions quite well, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list. Many of these contain some of the most valuable resources on that site. Is a check mark so important?

Comment: The very description of "Not Constructive" is *We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.*. I think that applies.

Comment: I did not ask for any opinions. I am looking for facts, statistics, or generalizations of those statistics, preferably supported by references. I am not asking for people to argue about one term or the other. I am not asking people "What do you personally use and where do you live?"

Comment: @Village: Just my take, but here's where I think your question runs afoul of EL&U guidelines: _"Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."_ Your question opened with _"Has anyone conducted a study on the terms used and geographic distribution of them?"_ I can imagine that – maybe not as a whole book – but certainly as a journal article. Yes, this question is a valid question about English usage – it would even make an interesting research project, if it's not been done yet. No, I wouldn't vote to reopen.

Answer (score 4):

In Australia, [to shout](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Shout) is used to mean to buy your mates something, usually a drink. I've also heard it being used as a noun, like in "this is my shout", meaning I'll get this one.

Answer (score 3):

Saying

> This meal is on John

means that John will pay for it.

Comment: Or *it's on me today* means that I am gonna pay today.

Answer (score 1):

"I suggest we (or Let's) split the bill" is also a common expression.

Technically, "splitting the bill" means calculating the entire expense then dividing it equally between all the participants. This is faster and more convenient, but could also be unfair to those who didn't order much.

Casually, "going dutch" can also be used to mean the same.